# Windows XP batch file concat

Tags: batch-file, cmd, text-files, concatenation, windows-console

I'm trying to accomplish the following ridiculous task:

I have a text file containing a set of fully qualified filesnames. I want to iterate through the file and append each line to a common variable, that can be passed to a command line tool. For example, the file might be:

> C:\dir\test.txt
>
> C:\WINDOWS\test2.txt
>
> C:\text3.txt

and I'd like to assign them to some variable 'a' such that:

```
a = "C:\dir\test.txt C:\WINDOWS\test2.txt C:\text2.txt"
```

A secondary question is - what is a good batch file reference? I'm finding some stuff in the Windows material, and a lot of home-grown websites, but nothing particularly complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As for references, [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/) isn't bad. [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php) gets linked fairly often, too.

---

As for your problem, that's easy:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set LIST=
for /f %%x in (yourfile.txt) do (
    set LIST=!LIST! "%%x"
)

echo %LIST%

endlocal
```

---

More in-depth explanation:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
```

We're enabling *delayed expansion* here. This is crucial as otherwise we wouldn't be able to manipulate the list of files within the `for` loop that follows.

```
for /f %%x in (yourfile.txt) do (
    set LIST=!LIST! "%%x"
)
```

`for /f` iterates over lines in a file, so exactly what we need here. In each loop iteration we append the next line to the `LIST` variable. Note the use of `!LIST!` instead of the usual `%LIST%`. This signals delayed expansion and ensures that the variable gets re-evaluated every time this command is run.

Usually `cmd` expands variables to their values as soon as a line is read and parsed. For `cmd` a single line is either a line or everything that *counts* as a line, which happens to hold true for blocks delimited by parentheses like the one we used here. So for `cmd` the complete block is a single statement which gets read and parsed once, regardless of how often the interior of the loop runs.

If we would have used `%LIST%` here instead of `!LIST!` then the variable would have been replaced immediately by its value (empty at that point) and the loop would have looked like this:

```
for /f %%x in (yourfile.txt) do (
    set LIST= "%%x"
)
```

Clearly this isn't what we wanted. Delayed expansion makes sure that a variable is expanded only when its value is really needed. In this case when the interior of the loop runs and constructs a list of file names.

Afterwards the variable `%LIST%` or `!LIST!` (now it doesn't really matter anymore which to use) contains the list of lines from the file.

Funnily enough, the help for the `set` command includes exactly this example for delayed expansion:

> Finally, support for delayed
>   environment variable expansion has
>   been added.  This support is always
>   disabled by default, but may be
>   enabled/disabled via the /V command
>   line switch to CMD.EXE.  See CMD /?
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion
>   is useful for getting around the
>   limitations of the current expansion
>   which happens when a line of text is
>   read, not when it is executed.  The
>   following example demonstrates the
>   problem with immediate variable
>   expansion:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
> ```
>
> would never display the message, since
>   the %VAR% in BOTH IF statements is
>   substituted when the first IF
>   statement is read, since it logically
>   includes the body of the IF, which is
>   a compound statement.  So the IF
>   inside the compound statement is
>   really comparing "before" with "after"
>   which will never be equal.  Similarly,
>   the following example will not work as
>   expected:
>
> ```
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```
>
> in that it will NOT build up a list of
>   files in the current directory, but
>   instead will just set the LIST
>   variable to the last file found.
>   Again, this is because the %LIST% is
>   expanded just once when the FOR
>   statement is read, and at that time
>   the LIST variable is empty. So the
>   actual FOR loop we are executing is:
>
> ```
> for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i
> ```
>
> which just keeps setting LIST to the
>   last file found.
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion
>   allows you to use a different
>   character (the exclamation mark) to
>   expand environment variables at
>   execution time.  If delayed variable
>   expansion is enabled, the above
>   examples could be written as follows
>   to work as intended:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
>
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```

Comment: Johannes: thank you for the thorough answer - I'm slightly more enlightened about batch-files now. I've got a related question you might be interested in that I've posted as a new thread here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506638/windows-batch-file-errorlevel-question

Answer (score 0):

What you're after can be done with a [FOR](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php) /F command.

Here's a good resource I've used many times:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php

Answer (score 0):

A good book:  Windows NT Shell Scripting by Tim Hill.  The edition I have was published in 1998 but it is still valid for Windows command programs in Windows 2008.

Answer (score 0):

```
type *commonfilepart* >> concat_result_file
```

OS: WINDOWS SERVER 2003