# Windows batch-file errorlevel question

Tags: scripting, batch-file, errorlevel

I've got a batch file that parses a bunch of file names out of a text file and concatenates them into a single strong - it was previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500570/windows-xp-batch-file-concat). However, I don't want the string to contain a file if the file throw an error when I run it through some command (like a VCS check, for example). Here's my attempt:

```
set FILE_LIST=
for /f %%x in (temp.txt) do (

:: perform a VCS test
accurev diff -b %%x

:: skip concatenation if error level is > 2
IF errorlevel 2 GOTO NEXT

:: perform the concatenation
set FILE_LIST=!FILE_LIST! %%x

:NEXT
:: print a message if here due to an error above
IF errorlevel 2 echo VCS problem with this file: %%x
)
```

The problem is - the script appears to stop executing the entire for-loop as soon as it finds one errorlevel greater than 2. If there are five files in the list and the third one has a VCS problem - the script only handles the first two.

Comment: It looks like the errorlevel is not reset on each iteration. Is it possible to manually reset it to 0 at the end of the loop?

Comment: mmyers: it would seem that the [advice from the internets](http://batcheero.blogspot.com/2007/07/never-set-errorlevel.html) is to never manually set the errorlevel variable.

Comment: ahh - I see hyperlink formatting does not work in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set FILE_LIST=
for /f %%x in (temp.txt) do (
    accurev diff -b "%%~x"
    IF errorlevel 2 (
        echo VCS problem with this file: %%~x
    ) ELSE (
        set FILE_LIST=!FILE_LIST! %%x
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> IF ERRORLEVEL construction has one
>   strange feature... it returns TRUE if the
>   return code was equal to or higher
>   than the specified errorlevel.

Reference [this link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php) to understand how to deal with that "feature".

Comment: that's what I'm after here - for this executable (accurev) the only "good" error levels are 0 or 1, so anything above 2 should be caught. I'm confused as to why it appears to bail out of the for-loop when it catches an error.