# DOS batch: SET variable and ECHO it within (...) block

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I had a problem with `set` not working in a batch file; it took a while to distil the problem; at first I thought it was to do with subroutine calls...

The script

```
@echo off
setlocal
set a=aaa
echo a = "%a%"
(
set b=bbb
echo b = "%b%"
)
```

produces the output

```
a = "aaa"
b = ""
```

whereas I'd expect

```
a = "aaa"
b = "bbb"
```

Why is this please? Is it a bug in DOS? Perhaps there's something about the `(...)` command grouping syntax that I'm unaware of.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

User delayed expansion and ! instead of %

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set a=aaa
echo a = "%a%"
(
set b=bbb
echo b = "!b!"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise reply. Do you happen to know if there's a syntax for the numbered parameters %1 etc.? I have tried !1 and !1!, but these don't work. (I'm asking this in the context of a :subroutine call.)

Comment: Since they can't change between parsing and execution the way %a% type variables can, I cant see that it matters.

Comment: You're quite right. I had other problems with the script that then exhibited the same symptoms. Problem solved. Thanks very much (to all).

Answer (score 7):

What's happening is that the batch interpreter as treating everything in between the brackets a single line.  This means it's doing variable replacement on everything betweeen the brackets before any of the commands are run.

So:

```
(
set b=bbb
echo b = "%b%"
)
```

Becomes:

```
(
set b=bbb
echo b = ""
)
```

The variable b is being set but obviously isn't set before you run the `SET` command.

Answer (score 6):

You need delayed expansion to be on, or the batch interpreter will interpolate all variables at parsing time, instead of run time.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500570/windows-xp-batch-file-concat) for an example and some great explanation of it.