# How to echo a variable set within a batch block, i.e., between parenthesis, after leaving the block

Tags: batch-file

Why does the following successfully echo %vol% whereas if I delete the goto done it will not echo %vol%?

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd d:
for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol') do ( 
set vol=%%6 & goto done
)
:done
echo.%vol%
pause
EXIT /b
```

This is a question similar to, but not the same as [DOS batch: SET variable and ECHO it within (...) block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687233/dos-batch-set-variable-and-echo-it-within-block)

Even without the goto done %vol% survives the end of the block since I can use it in comparisons, and even echo it using enabled expansion. I'm curious why just the echo command seems to be crippled with disabled expansion.

Comment: Because `vol` produces _two_ non-empty lines. The  6th token of the 1st line  is volume name while the 2nd line has only 5 tokens and its 6th token is empty…

Comment: Could you further explain how this relates to my question of having to use the goto done? Without goto done I get the empty response, but with the goto done I get the correct volume name.

Comment: `goto done` effectively breaks out of the `for` loop.  Without it, the loop continues to the next line and the next until all the lines are looped through.  The `vol` variable is set to the new value each time through the loop.  Once you're done with the loop, the final value that it was set to is its value.

Comment: Side note -- I would not recommend using %%1 as the `for` token since it is easily confused with `%1`.

Comment: Run the `VOL` command from a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I'm still not seeing the rationale. Without the goto done I am still exiting the loop and %vol% is (i repeat "is") set to the correct value. The only thing not working is echo.