# how to open a group of files from txt using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

For example, I've saved some links in list.txt:

```
d:\phpnow\htdocs\pm\includes\templates\slucky\common\tpl_gallery_display.php
d:\phpnow\htdocs\pm\includes\templates\slucky\common\tpl_main_page.php
d:\phpnow\htdocs\pm\includes\templates\slucky\templates\tpl_main_page.php
d:\phpnow\htdocs\pm\includes\templates\slucky\templates\tpl_product_info_display.php
d:\phpnow\htdocs\pm\includes\templates\slucky\templates\tpl_product_info_display2.php
```

I want to open them all in notepad++. Is there any plugin to do the job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a batch File called openfromfiles.bat and execute it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set LIST=
for /f %%x in (list.txt) do (
    set LIST=!LIST! "%%x"
    )
    echo %LIST%

"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++" %LIST%
```

here is the link for explanation of the batch file..
[Windows XP batch file concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500570/windows-xp-batch-file-concat)

Comment: It won't work if command like is too long. You have to create a session file to workaround it.

Answer (score 8):

Create a session file:

```
    <NotepadPlus>
        <Session>
            <mainView>
                <File filename="PATH_TO_FILE_1"/>
                <File filename="PATH_TO_FILE_2"/>
                <File filename="PATH_TO_FILE_#"/>
            </mainView>
        </Session>
    </NotepadPlus>
```

load it: File->Load Session...

Answer (score 5):

You do not need a new plugin. You can do that using command line and you have to give all files separated by space as command line arguments. You can find this detail from NotePad++ documentation. You can create a bat file for executing the command.

E.g:

```
<PATH_TO_NOTE_PAD++_FOLDER>/NotePad++.exe "PATH_TO_FILE_1" "PATH_TO_FILE2"
```

Answer (score 3):

Selected answer is not great - fails with long lists. Instead:

```
for /f %%x in (list.txt) do (
    start "" "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++" "%%x"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

For powershell script:

```
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$File
    )


    Get-Content -Path $File | foreach {& "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++" $_}
```

or powershell concole

```
    Get-Content -Path <File> | foreach {& "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++" $_}
```

Where  - list's file path
Well Done!

Answer (score 1):

I used Git Bash so that I could pipe the results of find into Notepad++:

`find . -type f -name "*.csproj" | xargs "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to just open all the files you normally would.
Then save session
Save the session file to a convenient location
Then open that file with Notepad++ whenever you want to open that batch of files.   No need to create scripts, batches or manually create a session file.

Comment: No sure why this got down-voted. Tried it out and it worked fine for me. (Close all files before you load the saved session.)

Comment: @FeralReason bcoz the question ask about how to open from a list. Which imho, the OP list of file should be **much** long longer.